# Creating a dynamic slot in Qt

Tags: qt, dynamic, signals-slots

I am trying to create slots dynamically and connect them. I am able to dynamically create pushButtons and connect them with existing slots. But what if I have a class with some member functions and I want to use these functions as slots.

From a general perspective, I want to create a template for generating slots given a function pointer. This allows us to create slots without changing the existing code and don't have to recompile using MOC.
If this doesn't make sense let me know. Thank you.

-CV

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It does make a lot of sense. I assume [`QSignalMapper`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsignalmapper.html) is not what you want. If your functions don't have arguments, maybe something like this is enough:

```
class SlotForwarder : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:

    typedef void (*Function)(); // or whatever. I never get this syntax right...

    SlotForwarder(Function function, QObject* parent = 0) 
        : QObject(parent)
        , m_fptr(function)
    {}

public slots:

    void forward()
    {
        m_fptr();
    }

private:

    Function m_fptr;
};
```

Create one for each function you want to encapsulate and connect to the `forward` as usual.

---

Now, if they *do* have arguments, maybe this Qt Quarterly article might be of assistance.

[**Dynamic Signals and Slots** by Eskil A. Blomfeldt](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qq/qq16-dynamicqobject.html)

The technique involves reimplementing the `qt_metacall` method yourself. The method has this signature:

```
int QObject::qt_metacall(QMetaObject::Call call, int id, void **arguments)
```

**Call** is the kind of metacall: slot, signal, property read or write, etc. Every slot has an **id**. The parameters are packed (by value or as pointers) inside the **arguments** array. Reading the code that the moc generates is a good way to understand how it all works.

Data about raw function signatures is available only during compile time, but slots are resolved at runtime. Because of that mismatch, you will need to wrap the functions into a template adapter type that  presents a constant interface to your implementation of `qt_metacall` and converts the `arguments` array into something the function can understand (cf. Python [*unpack*](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) operator). [Boost.Signals](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/signals.html) does that kind of [template hackery](http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/trunk/boost/signals/signal_template.hpp).

Comment: thanks for the code. This should work for normal functions but not for member functions. Do you know of a way to do this for a class member functions?

Comment: thanks andref. I figured out that member functions part using tr1::bind. I've posted my code below. I'll post a link once I have a small app for dynamic UI creation (incl. dynamic signal/slot connections).

Answer (score 3):

A continuation of andref's code so as to use any member function as a slot

```
    class SlotForwarder : public QObject
    {
        Q_OBJECT

    public:

        typedef void (*Function)();

        SlotForwarder(Function function, QObject* parent = 0) 
            : QObject(parent)
            , m_fptr(function)
        {}

    public slots:

        void forward()
        {
            m_fptr();
        }

    private:

        Function m_fptr;
    };

    int main(){
      QApplication a(argc, argv);
      MyClass myClassObject; //contains a function called MemberFunc
      //create a slotforwarder object so 
      SlotForwarder *memberFuncSlot = new SlotForwarder (std::tr1::bind(&MyClass::MemberFunc, &myClassObject));
      QObject::connect(ui.button,SIGNAL(clicked()),memberFuncSlot,SLOT(forward());
    }
```

Comment: Wow! `tr1::bind` is great and I had completely forgotten about it.

Comment: Interesting approach but when do you delete the forwarder in a normal program. I guess a smart pointer would be more sensible